# Ask Your Question button is disabled

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I wanted to ask my first question and after editing, I pressed the **Ask Your Question** button which become disabled and I couldn't press it.

I don't see any error messages on the page and the question is not on my asked questions list. I also don't see the question appear on the new questions page.

What did I miss?

[image: screen shot of broken ask button]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did exactly. You asked a question, went to edit and clicked the Ask a question button?

Comment: - I entered the Title
 - Wrote the question
 - added some tags
 - and pressed the button

(it is under Opera 10)

Comment: Definitely the right button? I've had no problems here with Opera 10

Comment: I could ask question here in meta and I pressed the same button

Comment: A link to your account would be useful.

Comment: http://superuser.com/users/11017/vereb

Comment: i added a screenshot

Comment: Do you have scripts allowed? ( specifically from sstatic.net and google )

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12800/posting-questions-does-not-work-any-more-in-opera-9-64

Comment: Yo, Freehand Circles, I'm really happy for you, I'ma let you finish, but Vereb had one of the best substitutes for you of all time!

Answer (score 3):

We moved most of the post validation to the server, which reduces the chance that JavaScript quirks will disable the submit button. Also, any submission errors can be simplified and placed in the same area on the form:

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6915/stackoverflowserverside.png

Answer (score 2):

Happens to me all the time in Opera.  If you've had a popup once (like, you forgot a tag) then the `Post Your Question` button is grayed out permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Something seems to have been broken with stackoverflow's scripts, I did get a "Content Encoding Error" in Firefox if I tried to load the scripts directly:

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

The wrongly encoded scripts got cached, but a *Shift-Reload* fixed the problem.

Comment: ctrl+f5 for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once, no idea what happened then. I think I just reloaded the ask-a-question page.

Comment: Was your title too short?

Answer (score 1):

Like John Smithers noted in the comments: see [Posting questions does not work any more in Opera 9.64](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12800/posting-questions-does-not-work-any-more-in-opera-9-64).

Answer (score 1):

Yea seems like its a Firefox thing, if the disabled attribute is on the button, even if the value is not set to "true", the button will be disabled.

So I just use Firebug and remove the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem some minutes ago. I discarded question, refilled the question form.
Closed, reopened browser. I made Ctrl+F5. But the issue is same.

Then I logged out and logged in to site. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I just got this in Safari 6.0.5

It seems to be a pan-browser thing based on what you all say.

One cause seems to be editing the tags and the tag-completion breaks.
That's how it happened to me.

The fix was to quit the page (multiple times) and reopen it (contents are restored from browser cache). Then the button is working again.