# Can't ask questions

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why can’t I edit some questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30532/why-cant-i-edit-some-questions)
>   [Ask Your Question button is disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22778/ask-your-question-button-is-disabled)

I'm trying to ask a question on stackoverflow but when I click "Post your Question", the button greys and the page stops. Tried firefox and chrome, same problem.

I don't know if meta works as well, if you can't see this question then it's got the same problem!!

UPDATE

Gaspar pointed out the question must be more than 15 characters, I didn't see the message. Sort it out atwood, I've now lost 3 minutes of productivity!

Comment: obviously meta does work

Comment: How long is your question's title? It needs to be 15 characters long or more and this validation isn't very visible.

Comment: Ah, it 14 chars, I'll try again

Comment: Gaspar saves the day once again!

Answer (score 3):

If the question title needs to be 15 characters long, and this isn't patently obvious to the poster, wouldn't this fall under the heading of "usability bug"?

Comment: Yeah, but Atwood'll never fix it. It's been brought up lots of times before.

Comment: I tried posting a question with a short title and a warning appeared below the title field.

Comment: That warning goes away when you start to type your question, I think. At least it did last time I checked.

Comment: UsabilityBug : Bug  .. I chose the base class

Comment: @Charlie: For tagging you made the right choice. But yeah, this is a dupe, and it's probably not getting addressed. :(

Comment: @Charlie: Yes, 'base class' is apt. I was, more or less, defending your assertion that this behavior is a bug.

Comment: @Jim G. Yeh ok I see. This bug needs to be fixed though. I'm going to use experts-exchange.com while jeff's fixing it.

Comment: Atwood doesn't fix usability bugs, he closes them as "by-design".