# Button to post new question is greyed out

Tags: bug, questions

I can't ask questions on Stack Overflow. The problem is that when I create a question the button at the bottom is grey (unavailable). And I can't submit it.

[image]

**EDIT:**
It somehow got fixed after a while. I have refreshed the page and the button became avalable again(I did refresh before, but nothing changed). So the problem is soved, but I still don't know what was causing it(JavaScript was enabled and I tried to change the tags without []).

Comment: The Post Your Question button?

Comment: You are not blocked from asking - what browser are you using? Are you getting any errors? Did you try reloading the page using Ctrl + F5?

Comment: using Chrome I don't think I am blocked from asking and I don't get any errors. And I have tried reloading the page and even discarding it and asking it again.

Comment: What site and did you try clicking? What does the button look like - can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Interesting rendering of the tags... Did you type them like that? ([Here's how it looks for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jpqQL.png).)

Comment: Do you happen to have JavaScript turned off?

Comment: @Oded Probably not. You can see there is a preview of the post in the screenshot. That requires JavaScript.

Comment: @Arjan yes I typed them like that. Also when I typed the tags no tags were suggested to me. But here in meta stackoverflow everything works fine.

Comment: Well, no need for the `[]` there, for one. Try without them (though the parser is smart enough to strip them out).

Comment: Have you tried clicking the button?

Comment: @Abe yes nothing happens

Comment: @Bosak Press inspect element and see if the button has any keywords that give clues that it's disabled.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22778/ask-your-question-button-is-disabled

Comment: I had a similar problem and i also had [] in my tags, as in byte[]. It might be related? I achieved a work-around by checking that "Answer my own question" box.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you don't get the nice looking [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) but only [tags], suggest me that you either have JavaScript disabled, or you are somehow blocking one of the JS files from Stack Overflow (or perhaps jQuery).

Check for that, and if JavaScript is enabled, check your console.